# UL list-style not applying on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am have made `e-commerce website` and i'm using `woocommerce plugin` to show products. My problem is that all are pages showing `list-style` in main menu but `plugins` pages are not showing up `list-style` .
I am also using [Responsive select menu plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-select-menu/) to create `responsive menu` .

[My site  url here](http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/makepeas-wp/)

[The page which is not showing li](http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/makepeas-wp/checkout/)

css

```
.nav{
    float:right;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 50px 8px 10px;
    margin-right: -13px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px -2px #5F5F5F;
}

.nav-strip{
    height:47px;
    width:49px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -45px;
    top: 0px;
    background: url(images/left-strip-nav.png) left no-repeat;
}

.responsiveSelectContainer>ul>li{
    float:left;
    list-style:square;
    margin-left:25px;
}

.responsiveSelectContainer>ul>li>a{
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.responsiveSelectContainer>ul>li:first-child{
    list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply create `Templates` for each page and its done.